# Can a set with an isolated point have a boundary?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

If I have a set formed by the union of $x^2+y^2\le4$ and the point $(5,5)$, does the set have a boundary in the form of a circumference centred at the point $(0,0)$ of radius $2$?

What I am asking is whether the point $(5,5)$ affects in any way the existence of the boundary given by $x^2+y^2\le 4$.

Thank you.

Comment: Before we answer, you should do some work.  What is the definition of "boundary"?  What happens when you apply that definition to this set?

Comment: Firstly the boundary depends on the topology/metric/norm you are considering. Do you work with the Euclidean metric?

Comment: It is a set of points for which every open ε-ball centred on each of those points contains at least one point in A and at least one point not in A. Nonetheless, the point (5,5) is neither a boundary point nor an interior point.

Comment: @PedroAdánGarcía: no. $(5,5)$ *is* a boundary point. Check the diagram here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)#Properties

Comment: Every isolated point of a set in $\Bbb R^n$ is a boundary point of that set. So $(5,5)$ is too. If $A$ is closed, every point of $A$ is either an interior point or a boundary point.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is
$$
S=\{x^2+y^2\le 4\}\cup \{(5,5)\}
$$

The interior of $S$ is the open disk $\{x^2+y^2< 4\}$. Since $S$ is closed, its boundary is given by
$$
\partial S
=\overline{S}\setminus \textrm{int}(S)
=S\setminus \textrm{int}(S)=\{x^2+y^2=4\}\cup \{(5,5)\}.
$$